# How do I find the surface area of a Torus using calculus?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, volume, surface-integrals

I managed to find the volume of a torus by solids of revolution, using the washers method. Can the same method be applied for finding an expression for the surface area?

Comment: Yes, usually classes cover both area under a curve and arc length, where the former is used in volumes of revolution and the latter is used in surfaces of revolution

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll do some reading into integrals and arc length. Does it only apply for rotating about the x-axis, or could I use the same apporach I used earlier (washers)?

Comment: For example here is wolframs math page on the idea http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceofRevolution.html and Paul's Online notes (my personal favorite) http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SurfaceArea.aspx

Answer (score 3):

One can find the area, using an analogous of the washers method, as follows.

If $O$ is the torus center and $C$ the center of the revolving circle, consider a point $P$ on that circle corresponding to an angle $\theta=\angle OCP$, and a point $P'$ close to $P$, corresponding to an angle $\theta+d\theta$. If $R=OC$ and $r=CP$, then the area of the stripe between the two circles obtained by the rotation of $P$ and $P'$ is: 
$$dA=2\pi\cdot PH\cdot PP' = 2\pi(R-r\cos\theta)(r\,d\theta).$$ 
Integrate that between $0$ and $2\pi$ and you are done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a toroidal coordinate system the computation of area is I believe most easy. However, *a hybrid* between spherical and cylindrical coordinate system can be adopted.

Let radius at crown be $b$, $R$ tube radius, $r$ variable radius of cyl coordinate system, and $\phi$ the latitude of spherical system. Area of torus =

$$ \int_{b-R}^{b+R} \int_{-\pi}^{ \pi} R\, d\phi \cdot 2 \pi\, dr = 2 \pi R \int_{-\pi} ^{  \pi} ( b- R \cos \phi)  d \phi = 2 \pi R \cdot 2 \pi b. $$

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting. I'm taking high school maths and a lot of the terminology you used is alien to me. I'm writing an assignment (I must be able to explain the maths behind what I am doing) and I wanted to choose something challenging (relative to my level). I'm gonna look into what you wrote.

Comment: Ah I didn't know! If you're in high school then you may have already met "integrals" in mathematics. If you didn't, then ignore my answer! I supposed you were a university student xD

Comment: No worries! Integrals (calculus in general) is a pretty central part of our syllabus. At best we are supposed to be able to find volumes for simpler shapes. We only deal with the Cartesian coordinate system so I'll have to look into ''spherical and cylindrical coordinate systems''. Is it possible to end up with an integral looking at the Cartesian coordinate system?

Comment: @Herman Cylindrical coordinates are defined as

$$
\begin{cases}
x = R\cos\phi \\
y = R\sin\phi \\
z = z
\end{cases}
$$

Whilst the spherical are defined as 
$$
\begin{cases}
x = R\sin\theta\cos\phi \\
y = R\sin\theta\sin\phi \\
z = R\cos\theta
\end{cases}
$$

With their opportune ranges (you may check on wikipedia).

Those coordinates are useful when you are dealing with curved surfaces like indeed torus, spheres, circumferences and so on. Cartesian coordinates are not adeguate to describe curved surfaces!